# How to have Grunt launch a packaged Chrome App

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, gruntjs, google-chrome-app

I've used the [yeoman chromeapp generator][1] to scaffold out a Google Chrome Packaged App. The instructions for that generator say running the command `grunt debug` should launch the packaged app in the Chrome App container, but it doesn't. Instead it opens the packaged app as a regular hosted web app in a tab. Though I am a Grunt noob I'm looking at Gruntfile.js trying to figure out why it doesn't launch the app as a packaged app in the app container, but can't see where the problem is. What's the proper way to get Grunt to launch a Chrome App?

Comment: Have you also filed a bug with Grunt? https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue with the Yeoman live-reload—not great for testing actual apps with background js, native permissions, etc.

To manually launch a Chrome app from a folder, I've been using this idiom: `~/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --load-and-launch-app=/path/to/chrome/app/"`

There's also this project [`chrome-app-livereload`](https://github.com/bestander/chrome-app-livereload) ([blog post](https://medium.com/@bestander_nz/live-reloading-chrome-apps-2a58d804c496#.85roupbvw)) which supposedly swaps out livereload's standard reload with one suitable for inclusion in an app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to `chrome://extensions`, check the box Developer Mode and then click Load Unpacked Extension and point it to your manifest file. This will load your app in a Chrome App Container.